# Radio button not included in post

Tags: php, html, netbeans

I am making a registration form that posts the values to a php file, but upon inspection of the post variable in netbeans, I saw that the radio button is not included in the array yet all the other input are.

Heres the code:

```
<form id="register" action="php/register.php" method="post">
  <h1>Please fill out as much as possible</h1>
  <h2>Would you like to register as a bulk buyer or a retail buyer?</h2>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="regForm left">
      <input type="radio" name="custType" value="Bulk"><label>Bulk buyer</label><br>
      <input id="bEmail" type="email" name="bEmail"><label>Email address</label><br>
      <input id="bPass" type="password" name="bPass"><label>Password</label><br>
      <input id="bComp" type="text" name="bCompany"><label>Company name</label><br>
      <input id="bContact" type="text" name="bContact"><label>Contact person</label><br>
      <input id="bOffice" type="tel" name="bOffice"><label>Office number</label><br>
      <input id="bMobile" type="tel" name="bMobile"><label>Mobile number</label><br>
      <input id="bVAT" type="text" name="bVat"><label>VAT number</label><br>
      <textarea id="bAddress" cols="17" rows="4"></textarea><label>Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="regForm right">
      <input type="radio" name="custType" value="Retail"><label>Retail buyer</label><br>
      <input id="rEmail" type="email" name="rEmail"><label>Email address</label><br>
      <input id="rPass" type="password" name="rPass"><label>Password</label><br>
      <input id="rMobile" type="tel" name="rMobile"><label>Mobile number</label>
    </div>
    <div class="regForm right">
      <label>Do you wish to receive additional email marketing from us? <input id="marketingCheck" type="checkbox" name="market"></label><br>
      <input id="regSubmit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"><a href="" id="cancelReg">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

At the moment I am doing nothing with the post in the php file.

I could post a screenshot of the post var in netbeans, but the site will not allow me.
Heres the result of `print_r($_POST);`
`Array ( [bEmail] => [bPass] => [bCompany] => [bContact] => [bOffice] => [bMobile] => [bVat] => [rEmail] => [rPass] => [rMobile] => [submit] => Register )`

I looked at the other post, but they seem to have just a typo in the code or the sort.

Thanks

Comment: have you "checked" the radio button before submit? only checked buttons will be seen in request (same for checkboxes)

Comment: Referrung to answer above: You can make one radio button selected by default using the ``selected`` attribute

Comment: Did you select radio button?

Comment: Lol, I feel like a idiot now. Perhaps I need to go and sleep. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

Be sure you have "checked" the radio button before submit? only checked buttons will be seen in request

or

```
 <input type="radio" name="custType" value="Bulk" selected>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for this. I submitted without selecting a radio button.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the radio button is saved in $_POST only if any of the choices was selected, so you will receive only that radio box value via POST which is checked

Comment: Yeah, thanks for this. I submitted without selecting a radio button. I would up vote you though if I could.

Comment: I'm happy that i can help you! I will wait for your reputation rise! :)